# How to move entries from one project to another in a one-to-many relationship without using the "attach" method?

Tags: laravel

I have a database schema where a project can have many entries, and each entry belongs to only one project (one-to-many relationship). I am trying to move entries from one project to another using Laravel Eloquent without using the "attach" method.

Here's the code I have so far:

```php
if ($request->projectToMergeEntries) {
    $projectToMerge = Project::findOrFail($request->projectToMergeEntries['id']);
    $projectToMerge->workLog()->attach($project->workLog->pluck('id'));
    $project->workLog()->detach();
}
```

However, I have been facing some issues with this approach, and I can't figure out how to achieve the desired result.

Can someone please guide me on how to properly move entries from one project to another within the one-to-many relationship, without using the "attach" method? Any alternative solutions or explanations of what I might be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you mean you want to copy entries to the other project or move them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are `detaching` from your `$project` I assume you want to move work logs from one project to another. Since each work log belongs to one project all we need to do is update the `project_id` field of the work logs to the `$targetProject->id`

```php
if ($request->projectToMergeEntries) {
  $projectToMerge = Project::findOrFail($request->projectToMergeEntries['id']);
 
  WorkLog::query()
    ->where('project_id', $project->id)
    ->update(['project_id' => $projectToMerge->id]);
}
```